# How do Stigmatas and compatibility rate determine how powerful a Pandora is?

Tags: freezing

I don't fully understand the way Stigmata works and how compatibility rate factors into all of it. Granted, I am only on chapter 25. Does the number of Stigmata determine how powerful the Pandora is? This seemed to be the case at the start of the manga, where it was stated that 6 is "elite" level and how all the characters emphasize how Kazuha had 20. But then, we see Rana and Satellizer being able to defeat third-years.

I noticed that Chiffon only has 4, but then you have Rana who has 6. Why is the former regarded as stronger if she has less? Is it possible for someone with 1 Stigmata to be stronger than someone with 5? Also, how does the compatibility rate factor into all of this?

I was hoping someone could just clear this up for me.

Comment: `Granted, I am only on chapter 25` there you have it, just keep reading ;)

Comment: Is the word you want "compatibility" or "capability"? You have written "catability" and "capatability", neither of which are words.

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Eumel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30039/how-do-stigmatas-and-catability-rate-determine-how-powerful-a-pandora-is#comment41822_30039) said in his comment, you should just keep reading. This answer will contain several spoilers and most likely will spoil a lot of the plot. So you have been warned

**(scroll down to the TL:DNS; if you want a practical answer without spoilers)**

To properly understand how `stigma's` work, you will first have to understand what the `stigma's` are.

> Stigma's are pieces of Nova's, either obtain directly from a Nova 's core, or from the original Nova Maria Lancelot. They are known for their urging signals of destroying everything.

The so called 'Compatibility' determines how much of the 'power' stored within the stigma can be used by the Pandora. Theoretically speaking this means that somebody with 10 stigma's with a bad compatibility could be weaker then somebody with 1 or 2 stigma's with a strong compatibility.

However in the world of freezing stigmas are not limited to just one type:

> Besides regular stigma there are also the `heroic stigma`, `A stigmatic body`, the `Type-Maria Stigmata`, `injection stigmata: plasma form`, `legendary Stigmata`, `Plasma Stigmata`, `Legendary Stigmata System`

Each and every one of these have their own pro's cons. And even though compatibility still plays a huge role, the type of stigma also does.

### TL;DNS:

Yes it possible for someone with 1 stigmata to be stronger than someone with 5. This can be due to a person having a different type of stigmata, or significant better compatibility with the stigmata.